# Documentation on in shell calculations?

Tags: bash

I have noted the following article and thought that there was some great information in this about how to perform calculations in bash:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40786/how-to-do-integer-float-calculations-in-bash-or-other-languages-frameworks

However, I am unable to force float calculations in bash using the proposed method. (Mac OS X with current bash kernel && CentOS 7):

```
    Non-Elevated Shell: ~/> $ echo "$((20.0/7))"
    -bash: 20.0/7: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".0/7")
    Non-Elevated Shell: ~/> $ bash --version | head -n 1
    GNU bash, version 4.2.46(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
    Non-Elevated Shell: ~/> $ l


    Mac Shell: ~/>$ echo "$((20.0/7))"
    -bash: 20.0/7: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".0/7")
    Mac Shell: ~/>$ bash --version | head -n 1
    GNU bash, version 4.3.42(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15.4.0)
    Mac Shell: ~/>$
```

Does anybody see what I am doing wrong with the above method? Is this method compatible with modern bash or has this deprecated?

I understand that I could use `bc` however I do note that this will take considerably longer as bc is an external command and not a shell builtin.

```
    Mac Shell: ~/>$ time echo "$((20/7))"
    2

    real    0m0.000s
    user    0m0.000s
    sys     0m0.000s
    Mac Shell: ~/>$ time echo 'scale=2; 20/7' | bc 
    2.85

    real    0m0.011s
    user    0m0.002s
    sys     0m0.006s
    Mac Shell: ~/>$
```

While this might not be an issue for me now it will definitely slow me down in the future when writing more complex scripts.

Comment: `echo "$((20.0/7))"` works in zsh. As far as I know, it's never worked in bash.

Comment: The "proposed method" is for "**`ksh93`**, **`yash`** and **`zsh`**".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current GNU Bash documentation on [shell arithmetic](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Arithmetic) states:

> Evaluation is done in fixed-width integers with no check for overflow, though division by 0 is trapped and flagged as an error. The operators and their precedence, associativity, and values are the same as in the C language.

There's no provision there for floating point.

Korn shell and Zsh support floating point arithmetic.